# How to query summary/group in devexpress with advanced queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress, phonejs

A simple query:

```
var viewModel = {
    dataSource: Application_with_Chart.db.nom_clasa_articole.toDataSource({
        select: ["id","product", "quantity"]
    })
};

return viewModel;
```

in SQL:

```
SELECT id,product,quantity
FROM nom_clasa_articole
```

This is simple, but I need a query with group by and sum:

```
SELECT id, product, SUM(quantity)
FROM nom_clasa_articole
GROUP BY product
```

How can I write this query in devexpress?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the question is about [DevExtreme Multi-channel applications](http://help.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/Documentation/Howto/Project_Templates#Multi-Channel_Application). They use OData services.

OData prodocol does not have direct equivalent to SQL `GROUP BY`. You have two options here:

1. Use [OData service operations](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/operations/#213_Invoking_Service_Operations) for grouping on the server side.
2. Perform grouping on the client in a `postProcess` handler as shown below.

Client-side grouping:

```
var viewModel = {
    dataSource: Application32.db.nom_clasa_articole.toDataSource({
        select: ["id", "product", "quantity"],

        postProcess: function(items) {
            // Grouping occurs here
            var groups = {};

            $.each(items, function() {
                var groupKey = this.product;
                if(!groups[groupKey])
                    groups[groupKey] = { quantity: 0 };

                groups[groupKey].quantity += this.quantity;
            });

            return $.map(groups, function(v, k) { 
                return { product: k, quantity: v.quantity }; 
            });
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: how can do something like: SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE NAME='JACK'?